# how to give width and heights for divs, img and etc. when using bootstrap frame work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a web site using bootstrap frame work. but I'm new to it. so i create some dives using default style classes and it is working responsively.

but the problem is I don't know how to give sizes for images or some divs because default things are not fulfill my requirenment always.

ex:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail"  style="background-color: #555658; min-height: 350px;">
        <div style="font-size:24px; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 10px; font-weight: normal; font-family: sans-serif; color: #fff;">Connect with Us</div>
        <div class="caption" style="color:#dddddd;">
            <img src="images/w9.png"/>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

how to set width and height to img ? What should i use % or px ?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src="images/w9.png" style="width: 400px; height: 200px;" />
```

or

```
<img src="images/w9.png" style="width: 70%; height: 35%;" />
```

or

```
<img src="images/w9.png" style="width: 400px; height: 35%;" />
```

or you can even do

```
<img src="images/w9.png" width="400px" height="200px" />
```

or

```
<img src="images/w9.png" width="90%" height="80%" />
```

Comment: but if I set those values using px, when I viewing using mobile and other small devices it is showing absolute values. but in default this frame work is working responsively reducing the size of image. I want to keep it happening while giving width size, without width sizes the float option also not working

Comment: @Yasitha so use the % examples i gave

Comment: Thank you. I will try using that.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use inline CSS. It is bad practice.

In order to override default properties of, say, `.thumbnail` define a CSS class like this:

```
.thumbnail.my-custom-thumbnail {
   width: 400px;
   height: 300px;
   // etc
}
```

`.thumbnail.my-custom-thumbnail` has a higher specificity compared to `.thumbnail` and any rules you define inside it will override rules defines in `.thumbnail`.

Also consider posting live examples for your CSS/HTML questions via [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) or a similar web site.

To learn more about specificity in CSS, please read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the grid classes to image if you want it to be responsive, like `<img class = "col-sm-6" src="images/w9.png">` or do as AlienArrays said

Comment: wow, either this is not the best answer for my question  I learned lot of things using your answer.
thank you.